# How to write a uint32 integer into a 4 bytes sequence using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, byte, uint32

I have declared a numpy ndarray containing a single unsigned integer:

```
import numpy as np  
foo=np.array([3600000],dtype='uint32')
```

I would like to store this array into a 4 bytes sequence. 
I have already tested a few options, such as the struct.pack() and struct.pack_into() methods, to no avail.
I have also tried the numpy.ndarray.tobytes() method, which converts the content of my array into a bytes object:

```
bar=np.ndarray.tobytes(foo)
```

Alas, the ouput byte object has a length of 4 bits!
How can I control the number of bits of my output bytes sequence?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: *"Alas, the ouput byte object has a length of 4!"*  I'm confused.  The array `foo` contains one element of type `uint32` (i.e. an unsigned 32 bit integer).  That's four bytes.  Why are you disappointed that the length of `bar` is 4?

Comment: Hi Warren! Thanks for your reply; the output byte object has a length of 4 bits! Sorry for the confusion; I will edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: `bar` is a `bytes` object with 4 *bytes*, not bits.

Comment: Thanks Warren! This definitely answers my question!

Comment: Not really related, but it's possible to convert it in the reverse direction `numpy.ndarray(buffer=<...>, shape=<...>, dtype=<...>)`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Warren Weckesser, the length of a `bytes` object is given in bytes, not in  bits.
So in this case, `bar` indeed has a length of 4 bytes.